# Is there a way to design var toyList as LiveData<List<ToyEntry>> in ViewModel?

Tags: android, android-jetpack

The following code is from the [project](https://github.com/enpassio/Databinding).

The author design `var toyList` as `LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>?` in MainViewModel.

I think that it would be better if I design `var toyList` as `LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>`, how can I do ?

```
class MainViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {  
    var toyList: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>? = null
        get() {
            return field ?: mRepo.toyList.also { field = it }
        }
    ...
}


class ToyRepository private constructor(private val mDatabase: ToyDatabase, private val mExecutors: AppExecutors) {
    val toyList: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>
        get() = mDatabase.toyDao().allToys
    ...
}



interface ToyDao {
    @get:Query("SELECT * FROM toys")
    val allToys: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the nullable LiveData by a non nullable LiveData, with the same approach, observing another LiveData, then you can use the Transformations:

```
val toyList: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>> = Transformations.map(mRepo.toyList) {
    it 
}
```

Comment: Thanks! your code works well,  and `val toyList: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>> =mRepo.toyList` works well too,  I can't understand why the author want to use `var toyList: LiveData<List<ToyEntry>>? = null  get() {...}` !, could you tell me ?

Comment: If the response it was good, please rate it! I suposed that the author use a nullable var to return the field data, to avoid fetch data again from the repo... but livedata is not recommended outside the viewmodel... avoid them in the repositories... in you need a reactive app in the future you could use Flow or Rx, and if you need only at same point reactivity, you could to implement the observer pattern